# asp.net sql datareader loop by columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

I have sql query in my asp.net webapp and the result is stored in datareader. Every row in datareader contains 10 columns. I want to fill table with these data. However, I have no idea, how to loop through columns in datareader. I need something like this:

```
while (vysledky.Read())
{
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    tab.Controls.Add(row);
    foreach (column in ((datareader(row)))  //it is not real code
    {
      TableCell cell = new TableCell();
      cell.Text = datareader(row).content;
      row.Controls.Add(cell);
    }
}
```

I hope you got the point. Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `FieldCount` property of the `SqlDataReader`:

```
while (vysledky.Read())
{
    // Iterate over each of the fields (columns) in the datareader's current record
    for (int i = 0; i < vysledky.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        var value = vysledky[i];

        TableCell cell = new TableCell(); 
        cell.Text = Convert.ToString(value); 
        row.Controls.Add(cell); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just do it through a `SqlDataAdapter`:

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString);
SqlCommand YourSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
YourSqlCommand.Connection = Conn;
YourSqlCommand.CommandText = "select * from yourtable";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(YourSqlCommand);

sda.Fill(dt);
```

At the point, your `DataTable` (`dt`) contains all of the data from your query.

Comment: Looks like its a ASP table not a DataTable

Comment: @Magnus ASP table?  I'm not following.  That's definitely a `DataTable` with complete data from the query of the `SqlCommand`.

Comment: @Shark he wants to fill an ASP table not a `DataTable`. In the question he is referring to `TableRow` not `DataRow`